# Mysql Regex Problem

Tags: mysql, regex

I want to find only those rows whose column 'col' c doesn't contain characters from a-1. So I don't know how to write script. I've succeed to write script which is opposite to this. Thanks in Advance.

```
select * 
  from tbl_comment c 
 where c.`message` regexp '{a-z}';
```

I need the script which will be opposite to this. I've tried "not regexp" but it doesn't work.

Comment: Is `a-1` a typo in your question? Should that be `a-z`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need square brackets, not braces:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_comment c
WHERE c.`message` NOT REGEXP '[a-z]'
```

You also need to be careful what you mean. The above matches any row that doesn't contain any letters in a-z. If instead you want to match rows that contain at least one character not in a-z then you need this instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_comment c
WHERE c.`message` REGEXP '[^a-z]'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select * from tbl_comment c where c.message regexp '[^A-Z]'
```

or:

```
select * from tbl_comment c where c.message not regexp '[A-Z]'
```

Character class specifiers should be in [square brackets](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/pattern-matching.html).

(I'm assuming you meant "A-Z", not "A-1")